# My C++ template failed: explicit specialization of non-template struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct, specialization, explicit

I'm using clang on mac and having:

```
$cat my.cpp
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
template<int i>
struct place_holder{};
place_holder<1> _1;
place_holder<2> _2;
template<typename T>
struct is_placeholder:public integral_constant<int,0>{};
template<int i>
struct is_placeholder<place_holder<i> >:public integral_constant<int,i>{};
template<typename T>
int check(T&& t){
    return is_placeholder<t>()::value;
}
int main(){
    int i=check<_1>();
    return 0;
}
```

The last line failed to compile:

```
my.cpp:13:27: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
    return is_placeholder<t>()::value;
                        ^
my.cpp:7:19: note: template parameter is declared here
template<typename T>
                ^
my.cpp:16:11: error: no matching function for call to 'check'
    int i=check<_1>();
        ^~~~~~~~~
my.cpp:12:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 't', but no arguments were
    provided
int check(T&& t){
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Really odd, my "struct is_placeholder" is really a template, right? Why it say it's not?

How to correct my program? Thanks!

Comment: [mcve], please. The error strongly implies you didn't compile the code you showed.

Comment: It should compile: https://godbolt.org/g/55Vud3

Comment: Just edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you confuse types and objects a bit.

For example, you have made a mistake trying to instantiate a template with `t`, which is not a type:

```
return is_placeholder<t>()::value;
                    ^^^^^^
                     here
```

Also, you have defined `check` as a function which accepts a single argument but you provide it with no arguments during the call.

I suggest you doing the next:

1. Make `_1` and `_2` types:

   ```
   using _1 = place_holder<1>;
   using _2 = place_holder<2>;
   ```
2. Change `check` function as follows:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   auto check() {
       return is_placeholder<T>::value;
   }
   ```

Then use as:

```
auto i = check<_1>();
```

Here is a fixed version: [**WANDBOX**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bRnBcmWQF89G6zCd)